# Debugging docker builds in jenkins server

Tags: docker

I have a Jenkins server which builds docker images (using the docker maven plugin).

These Builds normally take about 40 seconds. But sometimes they take up to 1.5 hours.

Now I am wondering why. And I am also wondering how I can debug the situation.
The output of the build in the jenkins console just tells me  that it hangs during the maven docker build. Example output where it hangs:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MY Docker Image MY Image 0.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> docker-maven-plugin:0.15.14:build (default-cli) > initialize @ docker-image-my-image >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< docker-maven-plugin:0.15.14:build (default-cli) < initialize @ docker-image-my-image <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.15.14:build (default-cli) @ docker-image-my-image ---
[INFO] Building tar: /usr/home/jenkinshome/workspace/JOB_NAME/source-repo/docker/image-my-image/docker-build.tar
[INFO] DOCKER> docker-build.tar: Created [my-image] in 69 milliseconds
```

And now it hangs.

Can I somehow watch at which operation docker is hanging?

**UPDATE**

The build also hangs on the host maschine, when started directly via docker build.
This is the end of the output of doing this with strace:

```
futex(0xc820028908, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)      = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1486567620, 329675667}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1486567620, 329756643}) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/docker.sock"}, 23) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1486567620, 330059768}) = 0
epoll_create1(EPOLL_CLOEXEC)            = 4
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 3, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=3892185696, u64=139659048782432}}) = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, NULL}, [2]) = 0
getpeername(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/docker.sock"}, [23]) = 0
futex(0xc820028908, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)      = 1
read(3, 0xc820349000, 4096)             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(3, "POST /v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%"..., 349) = 349
futex(0xc820028d08, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)      = 1
write(3, "7ff\r\nockerfile\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 2054) = 2054
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=57, ws_col=105, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=57, ws_col=105, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
) = 481, "Sending build context to Docker "..., 48Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
write(1, "\r\n", 2
)                     = 2
write(3, "0\r\n\r\n", 5)                = 5
futex(0xc820028d08, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)      = 1
futex(0x12d3a48, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULLStep 1 : FROM jboss-db
 ---> 74a0020a9922
Step 2 : MAINTAINER ***
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d38cbd5501b
Step 3 : USER root:root
 ---> Running in 64b14554d8be
```

And at this point it hangs

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of options here, and you'll have to feel out which one works best for you. You can:

- `strace` the process on the docker host.
- Use something like `sysdig` on the host, which is easier to use and more detailed.
- do printf debugging or some sort of logging that indicates your build is still alive to stdout/stderr and the `docker log -f <build container>` to see if it's the build that's stuck or the jenkins slave/master processes.

Any more detailed advice will probably need more information about your setup, what you mean by hang and which component is hung exactly.

Comment: I updated my question for clarification. To which process should I "strace" on the docker host? dockerd? It just does nothing ...

Comment: @Nathan no, you need to find the "container" process. That is the process your container shows up as and strace that.

Comment: @Nathan, I now see I misunderstood your question, it seems your `docker build` process is what hangs. For that you'll have to strace `dockerd` and the `docker-cli`. Look at the logs for the docker daemon, common causes of hangs are extremely large build contexts.

Comment: Thans for all  the help. I posted the strace output, it does not really tell me anything. strace on dockerd also outputs nothing interesing.

Comment: @Nathan is this the output you get with `strace -f` ? I suspect this is without the `-f` flag.